Ignoring thrown exceptions in an MSTest test
Suppose we wish to test the following method. It's a contrived network call that logs a warning if the request failed and then throws after three attempts.
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ContrivedNetworkRequest(ILogger<IContrived> logger, HttpClient client)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return response;

            logger.LogWarning("Warning!");
        }

        throw new ContrivedException("Error!");
    }

We want to only test that a warning log was recorded. That is, we don't want to test that the method throws. Throwing is tested elsewhere and we don't want to have two asserts testing both logging and throwing in the same test for this scenario.
Is there a way to tell MSTest V3 (with .NET 8) to just exit the tested method when an exception is hit as we're only interested in other functionality?

Can't the test simply catch and ignore the exception?

@David Oh my god you're right - never code on Saturday after a long Friday night. Can you post it as an answer please.

Why don't you use the [ExpectedException(typeof(ContrivedException))] attribute?

@PeterCsala Whoa! That's exactly what I was wishing existed. Very cool stuff and I never would have found it without your comment. No try/catch braces and even has descriptive overloads.

I'm glad that it helped you :)


Is there a way to tell MSTest V3 (with .NET 8) to just exit the tested method when an exception is hit

An exception already exits a method.  The test can simply catch that exception like any other code.  For example:
// arrange
var logger = CreateMockLogger();
var client = CreateMockClient();

// act
try
{
    ContrivedNetworkRequest(logger, client)
}
catch (ContrivedException) { }

// assert
// ...


Maybe catching explicitly ContrivedException. I would hate getting through this via a MockExceptions for example.


This is "in addition to" the accepted answer, not "instead of", and it's offered just in case you aren't already familiar with how break when thrown interacts with MSTest execution modes.

Executing MSTest in RUN mode
This exception will be ignored just the way you want.
[TestMethod]
public void Test_IgnoreException()
{
    try
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
    }
}


Executing MSTest in DEBUG mode
However, NullReferenceException is an example of an exception that is, by default, set to break on thrown. This means that, if you are running your tests in Debug mode, it will pause execution even though it's still going to catch and kill the exception.


Settings for Break When Thrown
If you would like to change the default for this exception specifically, you can uncheck the box in the popup, and I also wanted to show exactly where the break on thrown settings are managed.

